# AngularJS - Am I missing something in this Factory injection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cachefactory

I'm using the $cacheFactory to save some data in my cache and everything was working very good until today that I've decided to separate my cacheFactory into a single class called MyFactory.js. Now I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: tableCacheFactory is not a function
```

Because it's taking the injection as a simple method or something, does anybody know if I'm missing something here?

**main.js**

```
angular.module('main-component',
    ['my-component',
    'my-cache-factory'
    ]);
```

**MyFactory.js**

```
angular.module('my-cache-factory', [])

    .factory('tableCacheFactory', [
        '$cacheFactory', function ($cacheFactory) {
            return $cacheFactory('my-cache');
        }
    ]);
```

**MyService.js**

```
angular.module('my-component', [])

    .factory('my-component-service',
        ['$rootScope',
        '$http',
        '$q',
        'tableCacheFactory',
        function ($rootScope, $http, $q, tableCacheFactory) {

            function getMyData (prodNro) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise = deferred.promise;

                var dataCache = tableCacheFactory.get('tablecache');

                if (!dataCache) {
                    dataCache = tableCacheFactory('tablecache');  // TypeError: tableCacheFactory is not a function
                }

                var summaryFromCache = dataCache.get('tablecache' + prodNro);

                if (summaryFromCache) {
                    deferred.resolve(summaryFromCache);

                } else { 

                    $http({
                        method: ...
                        data : ...
                        url: ...
                    }).success( function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        var objectResult = {
                            "data": data,
                            "status": status,
                            "headers": headers,
                            "config": config
                        }

                        if (data.response) {
                            // Save to cache
                            dataCache.put('tablecache'+prodNro, objectResult);
                        }

                        deferred.resolve(objectResult);

                    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        ...
                    });

                }

                return promise;

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some misconception about how the `$cacheFactory` works.

In `var dataCache = tableCacheFactory.get('tablecache');` you are using it like it was a initialized Cache object containing another Cache object.

On the other hand `dataCache = tableCacheFactory('tablecache');` uses it like it was the `$cacheFactory` itself.

And both of them try to access record 'tablecache' in something that I think should already be the *tableCache* itself.

The error is exactly what it says it is. [As per the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache), calling `$cacheFactory('my-cache');` does not return a function to create more caches.
It returns a `$cacheFactory.Cache` object which has methods like `put(key, value)` and `get(key)`. Use those instead.

I'd change the whole structure of the caching *(note that the name of the factory is changed)*:

```
.factory('tableCache', [
    '$cacheFactory', function ($cacheFactory) {
        //Return what the name of the factory implies
        return $cacheFactory('tablecache');
    }
]);
```

And then use that without needing to do more weird 'tablecache' namespacing

```
function getMyData (prodNro) {
    ...
    var summaryFromCache = tableCache.get(prodNro);
    ...
    tableCache.put(prodNro, objectResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tableCacheFactory` was wrapped inside `my-cache-factory` module. So you need to inject the module first into your `my-component` module before using it. So it should be like this:

```
angular.module('my-component', ['my-cache-factory'])
```

Comment: Please see my edit question and the comment for the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

you defined your cache factory in the module my-cache-factory, but then never injected that module to your main component-service module. Do `angular.module('my-component', ['my-cache-factory'])` instead.

Comment: I don´t think so, please see my edit question. However if that was the case the line above the error will fail too but it doesn't